# Does the Android Emulator use a device tree?

Tags: android, android-emulator, emulation, android-source, device-tree

I have not been able to find how the Android Emulator is passed a device tree when it is started (if at all). In fact, the generated `dtb.img`/`vendor_boot.img` device trees are completely empty. They include a string

```
really dummy
```

Does the Android Emulator use device tree blobs like a real system would? If so, where can I find it in the AOSP build tree? If no device trees are used, how does the AOSP kernel get platform information?